# ASP.NET VB Nested Listviews appearing side by side

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net, listview

I currently have a parent Listview and its child Listview displaying in the centre column of an HTML page that consists of three columns left, centre and right. And all looks very good. 
However I would like to display the child list view in the right column beside the parent list view.

To do this it seems I must somehow generate from the code behind page a new row in the table every time the parent Listview displays a record of its data and then some column HTML so the first child list view will appear in the right hand column.

If anyone can guide if this is the best approach and how to do it, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm rather surprised that you haven't gotten a response to this question in the month and some change that it's been since you posted it.

My suggestion would be to use an updatepanel (Ajax) and do just what you thought you should: When an item is selected in the parent listview, dynamically load the second listview.

Just a suggestion.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I am currently using Ajax and the child listview displays succesfully in the same column as the parent listview. The parent listview is displaying several items similar to how Amazon displays several items about a book (picture title description etc) and the child listview also displays several items. The website will be uploaded shortly in its current state which is OK but I would prefer the child listview to be displayed in an adjacent column beside the parent listview. This doesn't appear to be possible as HTML coding isn't allowed inside a listview.

Comment: I'll take a look at duplicating the issue you're experiencing. Are you including the columns within different updatepanels? Because if you are, that would be what's causing the problem. The listviews would have to be within the same updatepanel for them to communicate with each other.